# SuperAnnuation - Investment Style

Tags: superannuation

I am current 21 years of age and have a SuperAnnuation of $16,073.68 with BTSuper - $186.35 is invested per fortnight.

**What I am looking for:**

Given the fees listed below, my current contributions and the fees associated, are there any recommendations towards/against **high-risk** investments as opposed to **conservative** investment styles?

Here are a few particulars on my investment:

- Yearly Admission Fee: $78 Plus 0.45% pa of your account balance (this is nil for the Super Cash option).

The following fees exist depending on the type of investment:

- BT Super for Life - Lifestage Funds   0.36
- BT Super for Life - Growth Fund   0.20
- BT Super for Life - Moderate Fund 0.28
- BT Super for Life - Conservative Fund 0.18
- BT Super for Life - Super Cash    0.00

I've had a look at their [past performance information](https://btsfl.bt.com.au/investor/content/$ROOT$/content/dam/secure/btsfl/fragments/documents/pdfs/bt_sfl_past_performance.pdf) and can see some basic information about my current performance:

[image: Basic Snapshot of Account Performance]

At present stage, I have the following contribution type:

- 5% Lifestage Fund
- 5% Growth Fund
- 15% Moderate Fund
- 35% Conservative Fund
- 40% Super Cash Fund

**Sub-questions/contributing questions**

By placing 50%/45% into a low-risk conservative and Super Fund investment option, I fear I will not make much return on the investments, but will have a more stable income. Of course market(s) rise and drop, and cannot be assumed, but is there a **general ruling** towards how long/how much you invest in high-risk returns before deemed unstable? Is there any (I surmise there is) pro/con to investment style(s), and is there a independent standard for when/where you should invest in high-risk return, and low risk return?

**Some Findings**

- I went and looked into AMP's [results](https://www.amp.com.au/news/2017/august/how-much-super-should-i-have-at-my-age) and noted I am ahead of the "average" for super; I put this down to the fact I skipped University/College. Furthermore, it's not just about averages.
- I also used their "estimator" (and whilst I *hope* my salary increases over time) my retirement value is estimated to be $284,008(^1) at age 70 (and yes, I understand there are too many variables for this to be accurate). Based on this figure [here](https://www.canstar.com.au/superannuation/how-much-super-for-retirement/), that is less than 5 years of expenses covered.

(^1) Note that this [tool](https://www.industrysuper.com/retirement-info/retirement-calculators/retirement-balance-projection/) provides a much more positive outcome.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Does the edit improve the overall question?

Comment: Yes, the additional focus I believe helps make it more answerable.